# MS Word TOC - Level 4 page number WILL NOT align

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

Does anyone know how to align the page numbers for level 4 in a MS Word TOC? Rather annoyingly they will not line up for the fourth level and I cannot find the setting to resolve the issue.

Number alignment in MS Word TOC:

[image]

Comment: Better post an example document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to edit the paragraph style in you ToC:

1. Right-click on the ToC and choose "Edit Field"

[image]

2. Click on "Table of Contents"

[image]

3. Click on "Modify"

[image]

4. Select "TOC 4" then click on "Modify"

[image]

5. Right-Click on "Format" then select "Tabs"

[image]

6. Fix the position of the tab and you should be good to go

Comment: Thank you so much.  This was driving me mad!!!  All resolved now!

Comment: Ok I had just about reached the point where I thought I was schizophrenic, because I was sure there was a menu for the ToC but couldn't find it. Sometimes word makes me doubt my sanity

Comment: YESSSS, finally I found the correct answer.